# How to create Seuratobject using 3 samples

Tags: seurat

I have total of 6 scRNA seq data samples which can be divided into group A and B. I would like to create Seuratobject A and B by combining 3 samples counts data for each group. Eventually I would like to see UMAP with colored by group A and B. I tried many ways but failed. I can see UMAP with 6 colors representing 6 samples. Could you please help me with this issue?
Please find below my code for your reference-

```
A1.data <-Read10X(data.dir = "C:/Users/mad1188/Box/SequencingData/cellranger_count/-A-7-1/filtered_feature_bc_matrix")
A2.data <-Read10X(data.dir = "C:/Users/mad1188/Box/Sequencing Data/cellranger_count/-A-7-2/filtered_feature_bc_matrix")
A3.data <-Read10X(data.dir = "C:/Users/mad1188/Box/Sequencing Data/cellranger_count/-A-7-3/filtered_feature_bc_matrix")
A1 <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = A1.data,
project = "A7")
A2 <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = A2.data,project = "A7")
A3 <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = A3.data,project = "A7")
head(x = colnames(x = A1))
A1 <- RenameCells(object = A1, add.cell.id = "A7")
head(x = colnames(x = A1))
head(x = colnames(x = A2))
A2 <- RenameCells(object = A2, add.cell.id = "A7")
head(x = colnames(x = A7))
head(x = colnames(x = A3))
A3 <- RenameCells(object = A3, add.cell.id = "A7")
head(x = colnames(x = A3))
A1[["percent.mt"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(object = A1, pattern = "^MT-")
A2[["percent.mt"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(object = A2, pattern = "^MT-")
A3[["percent.mt"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(object = A3, pattern = "^MT-")
p1 <- VlnPlot(object = A1, features = c("nFeature_RNA", "nCount_RNA", "percent.mt"), ncol = 3)
p2 <- VlnPlot(object = A2, features = c("nFeature_RNA", "nCount_RNA", "percent.mt"), ncol = 3)
p3 <- VlnPlot(object = A3, features = c("nFeature_RNA", "nCount_RNA", "percent.mt"), ncol = 3)
CombinePlots(plots = list(p1, p2, p3), ncol =1)
p4 <- FeatureScatter(object = A1, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "percent.mt")
p5 <- FeatureScatter(object = A1, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "nFeature_RNA")
p6 <- FeatureScatter(object = A2, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "percent.mt")
p7 <- FeatureScatter(object = A2, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "nFeature_RNA")
p8 <- FeatureScatter(object = A3, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "percent.mt")
p9 <- FeatureScatter(object = A3, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "nFeature_RNA")
CombinePlots(plots = list(p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9), ncol =2)
A1 <- subset(x = A1, subset = nFeature_RNA > 200 & nFeature_RNA < 8000 & percent.mt < 20)
A2 <- subset(x = A2, subset = nFeature_RNA > 200 & nFeature_RNA < 8000 & percent.mt < 20)
A3 <- subset(x = A3, subset = nFeature_RNA > 200 & nFeature_RNA < 8000 & percent.mt < 20)
p10 <- VlnPlot(object = A1, features = c("nFeature_RNA", "nCount_RNA", "percent.mt"), ncol = 3)
p11 <- VlnPlot(object = A2, features = c("nFeature_RNA", "nCount_RNA", "percent.mt"), ncol = 3)
p12 <- VlnPlot(object = A3, features = c("nFeature_RNA", "nCount_RNA", "percent.mt"), ncol = 3)
CombinePlots(plots = list(p10, p11, p12), ncol =1)
p13 <- FeatureScatter(object = A1, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "percent.mt")
p14 <- FeatureScatter(object = A1, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "nFeature_RNA")
p15 <- FeatureScatter(object = A2, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "percent.mt")
p16 <- FeatureScatter(object = A2, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "nFeature_RNA")
p17 <- FeatureScatter(object = A3, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "percent.mt")
p18 <- FeatureScatter(object = A3, feature1 = "nCount_RNA", feature2 = "nFeature_RNA")
CombinePlots(plots = list(p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18), ncol =2)
```